# How to turn of grid in print layout in QGis?

Tags: qgis, print-composer

do you know how to turn of this grid lines in print layout in QGIS? I turned off my grid lines, but I don't know how to remove them.[image]

---

@katagena
What do you mean?

@BERA
Yes, it is.

@bloigge
It is .ecw file, and probably it's something wrong with it, cause I changed background layer to another map which is .jpg and grid had gone.

Comment: Do you have a theme?

Comment: Is that a point layer?

Comment: which type is your background layer? Could be an issue with WMTS